# Не приходят апдейты от телеграмм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пишу бота, все апдейты ловит и корректно их отрабатывает, но вот при нажатии на inline кнопку не приходит апдейт. Пожалуйста подскажите что сделать.
Вот код который ловит апдейты:

```
dp = Dispatcher(storage=MemoryStorage())
dp.include_routers(lightning_router, game_router,
                   weather_router, smart_router, horo_router)
dp.include_router(cansel_router)

bot = Bot(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
webhook_uri = 'my-app-url' + '/' + str(os.getenv('TOKEN'))


async def start():
    await set_bot_commands(bot)


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    await start()
    print(await bot.set_webhook(url=webhook_uri), 'webhook was set')
    yield
    print(await bot.delete_webhook(), 'webhooks was deleted')
    await bot.session.close()


app = FastAPI(docs_url=None, lifespan=lifespan)


@app.post('/' + str(os.getenv("TOKEN")))
async def webhook_response(update: dict):
    print(update)
    return await dp.feed_update(bot=bot, update=Update(**update))


@app.get('/')
async def alive():
    return "Alive"
```

проверяю через принт в функции webhook_response, обычные команды и сообщения принтятся, но при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит

Answer (score 0):

нашел ответ: в методе `set_webhook()` надо передать список с апдейтами, которые я хочу получать, то есть месседж и колбек квери.